# Given a checkbox object output its value

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, jquery-events

I have a page that has a number of checkboxes in it. I would like to write a function that will be called when the ckeckbox is clicked, that determines if the checkbox is checked or not.

```
<input type="checkbox" onclick="toggleVis('id',   this);"/> ID
<input type="checkbox" onclick="toggleVis('edit', this);" checked="checked"/> Edit
<input type="checkbox" onclick="toggleVis('last', this);"/> Last
```

Note some checkboxes start checked.

I figured that there must be a way to do this based on a reference passed, so I passed the this value as a parameter.

```
function toggleVis(name, checkbox)
{
    //if(checkbox.checked())
        console.log('checked');

        if($('.'+name).css('display') != "none")
            $('.'+name).css('display', 'none');
        else
             $('.'+name).css('display', 'table-cell');
}
```

I am open to use jQuery.

Comment: Did your code work? If not what happened? Get Firebug and see what the objects passed actually are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close.

```
if(checkbox.checked) {
    console.log('checked');
    //...
}
```

There's no `checked()` method, but there is a `checked` property. Note that your code may only work on clicks. Perhaps `onchange` would be better?

Answer (score 1):

Look at the `checkboxobj.checked` property (instead of calling it like a function). In your case, you could reference `if (checkbox.checked) { ... }`. More information can be found [on this website](http://www.javascriptkit.com/jsref/checkbox.shtml#e1)

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to do this with jQuery you might try the following. Note that I'm binding to the checkbox instead of including the 'onclick' or 'onchange' directly on the HTML element.

```
$('[type=checkbox]').click(function(){
  if( $(this).attr('checked') ){
    console.log('checked');
    if($('.'+$(this).attr('name')).css('display') != "none") {
      $('.'+$(this).attr('name')).css('display', 'none');
    } else {
      $('.'+$(this).attr('name')).css('display', 'table-cell');
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

And a JQuery-based solution:

```
var checked = $(checkbox).is(':checked');
```

Helpful if you want to find the checkbox first by some JQ selector.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="checkbox" class="checkthis"> ID
<input type="checkbox" class="checkthis" checked="checked"> Edit
<input type="checkbox" class="checkthis"> Last

$(input.checkthis).click(function() {
  if($(this).is(':checked') {
    // do checked stuuf
  } else {
    // do not checked stuff
  }
});
```